# Giuoco Piano, Steinitz Variation

Tags: opening, italian-game

```
[fen ""]    

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. Bc4 Bc5 4. c3 Nf6 5. d4 exd4 6. cxd4 Bb4+ 7. Nc3 Nxe4 8. O-O Bxc3 9. bxc3 d5 10. Ba3
```

Steinitz Variation.

We play this in regular tournaments and it is very interesting. White gives the sacrifice of Bishop and also blocks Black's ...O-O. When we studied this line it contains lot of interesting variations. In modern times most players are not playing this variation, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line looks unsound.

White's plan seems to be to threaten to win back the piece by **10...dxc4 11. Re1** (pinning the knight), teasing Black into weakening his king's position further by **11...f5** to defend e4, which then leads to a very complicated situation that White hopes to manage better.

However, Black is fine if he just lets go of the knight, since he's still a pawn up. Obviously, his kingside is very weak, but he can move out his queen with tempo (by attacking e4) and castle long.

**11...Be6 12. Rxe4 Qd5 13. Re1/Re2/Qe2 etc. 0-0-0**

The black king is safe and c4 is actually well protected. White doesn't have enough compensation left for that pawn.

---

To back this up, according to the Lichess online database, White has a win rate of 62% if Black plays **11...f5** (71 games), but only one of 27%/38% respectively if the answer is **11...Qd5** or **11...Be6** (11/8 games). **11...Bf5** also seems to work (35%, 20 games).

That's just not enough to make the variation appealing for grandmasters (who probably consider the refutation too obvious), and if none of them play a line it will hardly become very popular. It's a nice Blitz surprise weapon though, as you can see the majority of players from a database leaning towards fast games will choose 11...f5.

Comment: Sir, Excellent!!